# render offline vector .map file in iOS

Tags: ios, maps, offline

I have a .map file that I used to render maps on Andriod using mapsforge. I am trying to do the same thing in iOS.

I have tried using route-me library and followed the following [tutorial](http://shiki.me/blog/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me/)  but the problem is that the map that I get is a picture base map not a vector map which makes the file size very large. the .map file that I have is running on iOS device perfectly and its size is relatively small about 13 MB for the same region of the same file I used with route-me in iOS.

Can anyone please point me to a tool or library even if paid for drawing vector maps in iOS for offline usage.

YES; I tried running [this application](https://github.com/medvedNick/Mapsforge_iOS) but I keeps getting errors in the application like ProtocolBuffer.h is not defined.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see my answer below, It is not supported on the version that I was using for iOS, I am not sure if they are supporting it in a newer version. I ended up using openstreetMap, I had to download the whole map file to the iphone to use it offline.

Comment: I wanted to prevent to use MapBox... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I was unable to create an offline vector map, but I was able to create an offline tiled map using openstreetMap as data source and Mapbox as rendering tool in ios.